# Can you identify the hostname of machine where a webpage is hosted?

Tags: ssh, hostname, url

At my company, there is an internal cgi script that I regularly use. Is there any way I can identify the hostname of that machine by just the url? Unfortunately, the hostname is not within the url. What I want to do after is to access that machine with a hostname and do an ssh login, if possible. I'll also want to view the contents of the cgi script. If there are other ways to go about this, I'm all ears. Thanks.

Comment: Are you in IT?  I would work with the IT admins...even if you have the hostname, having SSH access is still something IT will need to grant.  Going around that would not be wise.

Comment: What's the path to the script?  Why can't you just look at your open mount points if it's not located at hostname/script.cgi?

Comment: I believe my IT would ask me what machine do I need access to. The problem is I do not know what machine that is.

Comment: So tell IT "I'm not sure, here's how I access it."

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't. Ask your IT department to give you the details and access to the server.

Comment: I do have access to the server. Or I have rights to give myself access to that server. In either case, I can't verify I have permission (or even ask someone for permission) unless I know what server to begin with...